# How to know and learn about those java component?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, orm

I am quite new to java and trying to start learning Java spring boot frame work with Object relational Mapper . Just got one sample project to study. But I am not able to understand components and its uses. I have attached an image. I would highly appreciate for a small intro and tips to work further in this project. Currently I am not able to understand well about different component like config ,controller ,domain , service and and repository used in this project.

source code : https://github.com/zlict/m223-punchclock
[image]

Comment: https://spring.io/guides

I thought Spring Boot was pretty weird and confusing when I started working with it as well.  Work through Spring's own guides and tutorials to get a feel for what can be done and how it all happens, then come back here when you have more specific questions about how to make some particular thing work.

That's the approach I have taken over the last few months, and it has helped a lot :)

Comment: In addition to what @sunrise said, you should really take a step back and learn each piece by itself rather than taking on an entire framework without knowing the language.